# Hiding and fading in an element in jQuery behaving weirdly due to CSS transition duration

Tags: jquery, css-animations, fadein

I have an element (a circle) that I would like to add to the page and fade in. I am using the following jQuery to do this:

```
var circle = $("<div id=\"circle\"></div>");
circle.hide();
circle.appendTo("body");
circle.fadeIn(1000);
```

Initially this works fine. I've then added the some CSS to the circle to change its size when it is hovered over or clicked and made this animate by adding `transition-duration: 0.2s;` to the circle.

Now, when the fade in happens the circle appears instantly, fades out somewhat and then fades in; presumably due to `circle.hide();` using its transition duration. [JSFiddle demonstrating the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/ru8dxtv7/).

Is there a simple way to either:

1. Add the circle element initially hidden and fade it in, or
2. Handle the animation of the circle's size in jQuery instead of using CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just be more restrictive in your CSS `transition` property.
Currently, setting only the `transition-duration: 0.2s` is like setting a `transition: all .2s 0s ease`.

You can choose to animate only the [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) you need :

```js
var circle = $("<div id=\"circle\"></div>");
circle.hide();
circle.appendTo("body");
circle.fadeIn(1000);
```

```css
html {
 background-color: #000;
}
#circle {
 border-radius: 50px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #fff;
  /* change just this line */
    transition: width .2s, height .2s, border-radius .2s;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
#circle:hover {
 border-radius: 60px;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
}
#circle:active {
 border-radius: 55px;
 width: 110px;
 height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the best and simple way, but that works without changing anything else: you can remove the `transition-duration` from your css, then set it with jquery when `fadeIn` method is complete

```
var circle = $("<div id=\"circle\"></div>");
circle.hide();
circle.appendTo("body");
circle.fadeIn(1000, function() {
    circle.css('transition-duration', '0.2s');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a short timeout at the very end of that function, then add a class to the circle. The class would have all the CSS transitions. So there's no chance of any interference since the circle will not have any transitions until the initial fadein is done.

```
      setTimeout(function() {
         circle.addClass('active');
      }, 300);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/vr2g77hv/)